# Динамичный плейлист на php

Tags: xml, php

Подскажите скрипт php, для добавления элементов в плейлист:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<songs>

   <settings template="skins/newbg.jpg" textcolor="0xFFFFFF" autostart="yes">
   </settings>

   <song>
      <title>Emotive - Passive</title>
      <artist>A Perfect Circle</artist>
      <url>songs/passive.mp3</url>
   </song>
   <song>
      <title>Seperate Ways</title>
      <artist>Journey</artist>
      <url>songs/journey.mp3</url>
   </song>
   <song>
      <title>And Justice For All - One</title>
      <artist>Metallica</artist>
      <url>songs/one.mp3</url>
   </song>
   <song>
      <title>Mystical Druids Society</title>
      <artist>Mind Distortion System</artist>
      <url>songs/system.mp3</url>
   </song>

</songs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код записывает xml файл в массив

```
if (file_exists('test.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

    var_dump($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}
```